# Flutter statefulwidget doesn't change state

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget

cupertinoDatePicker doesn't work. that button value doesn't change. What can I do? I think `widget.date.year` doesn't work.

`MyHomeWiget`

```dart
class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHome({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHome> createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {

  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  final _number= TextEditingController();
  List todoList=[
  ];
  DateTime dateTime = DateTime(2022,11,11);

  void checkBoxToggle(bool? value, int index){
    setState(() {
      todoList[index][1]= !todoList[index][1];
    });
  }


  void createNewToDo(){
    showDialog(
      context:context ,
      builder:(context){
        return TodoDialog(
          controller: _controller,
          onSave:onSave,
          numberController: _number,
          date: dateTime,
          onDateTimeChanged:(DateTime newTime){
            setState(()=> dateTime=newTime );
            print(dateTime);
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

`DialogWiget`

```dart
class TodoDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  

  final controller;
  final numberController;
  VoidCallback onSave;
  final DateTime date;
  Function(DateTime) onDateTimeChanged;

  TodoDialog({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
    required this.onSave,
    required this.numberController,
    required this.date,
    required this.onDateTimeChanged,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      content: Container(
        height:350,
        width: 300,
        padding:EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Add a new todo",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color:Colors.black)
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.black
                  )
                )
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller:numberController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Time",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color:Colors.black)
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.black
                  )
                )
              ),
            ),
            DatePicker(
              onDateTimeChanged: onDateTimeChanged,
              date: date,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                MyButton(
                  text: "save",
                  onPressed: onSave,
                ),
                SizedBox(width:10),
                MyButton(
                  text: "Cancel",
                  onPressed: (){},
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`DatePickerWidget`

```dart
class DatePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  final DateTime date;
  Function(DateTime) onDateTimeChanged;
  DatePicker({super.key,required this.date, required this.onDateTimeChanged});

  @override
  State<DatePicker> createState() => _DatePickerState();
}

class _DatePickerState extends State<DatePicker> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: CupertinoButton(
              child: Text('${widget.date.year}. ${widget.date.month}. ${widget.date.day}'),
              onPressed:(){
                showCupertinoModalPopup(
                  context:context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context)=>SizedBox(
                    height: 250,
                    child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      onDateTimeChanged: widget.onDateTimeChanged,
                      mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                    ),
                  )
                );
              }
            ),
    );_
  }
}
```

MyHome(pressed button)->show DialogWidget->dialog has Datepicker

I expect Text(widget.date.year ....) this line doesn't work. please help me!!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is not working here?

Comment: i run your code and its working fine. the `year`, `month` and `day` are all updating as you scroll the ticker. you just need to wrap your CupertinoButton with scaffold so that its not showing a black background.

Comment: can you confirm my picture?

Comment: Do you mean doesnt change on dialog ?

Comment: yes dialog doesnt change